# AWS Cognito login using username and Facebook at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want my users to be able to use username + password login or facebook login, where they will add username afterwards. How should I set up cognito to make this working?

When I set username as main login option, I can not add Facebook to Identity providers because of:

```
The attribute mapping is missing required attributes [birthdate, gender, name, nickname] (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 33685466-642a-11e9-808c-db0b9bb00ea9)
```

Is there a proper way to handle this login thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your are using Federated Identities (Login with Facebook, Amazon or Google for example), the authentication is made on the identity provider (Facebook in your case) and then a profile is created in your Cognito User Pool, by importing attributes from the IDP.

High level identity federation is detailed here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html

When you have mandatory attributes defined in your Cognito User Pool, you need to tell Cognito how to map attributes from the IDP to your Cognito User Pool attribute.  For example if you have a "birthdate" mandatory attribute in Cognito, you need to tell Cognito where it can get this value from Facebook's profile.

This is attribute mapping and this is explained here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html

The solution to the above issue is

a/ either remove these attributes from the list of mandatory attributes in Cognito.  This is the option to choose if your IDP does not have this information. (Can facebook share birthdate and gender attribute ?)

b/ either define an attribute mapping to let Cognito know where it can fetch these attributes in the IDP (Facebook) profile.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that is is good to use username or federal id as "username" and then use preferred username for both?

Comment: Using the default settings, Cognito User Pool generates username like `Facebook_10157116229128058` (Facebook ID mapped to Cognito's username) You are free to map the same facebook attribute ("id") to multiple Cognito attributes (username and prefered username for example)

Comment: No you cant, you can only map one facebook attribute to one cognito attribute, it is kinda one to one, not sure is it a bug (though console)